# Set JScrollPane's height relative to its parent container's height

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jscrollpane, gridbaglayout

I have a `JScrollPane` containing a `JTable` in a `GridBagLayout`. When I resize my `JFrame` containing the layout pane, the table resizes horizontally but not vertically. Even if I have `GridBagConstraints.fill` set to `GridBagConstraints.BOTH`. I want to have a `JScrollPane` resizing vertically and horizontally depending on the size of its parent container (→ the `JFrame`).

```java
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;

public class GridBagPanel extends JPanel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public GridBagPanel() {

        super(new GridBagLayout());

        String[] columns = { "Column 1", "Column 2", "Column 3", "Column 4" };
        String[][] contents = { { "Content 1", "Content 2", "Content 3", "Content 4", "Content 5" },
                { "Content 1", "Content 2", "Content 3", "Content 4", "Content 5" },
                { "Content 1", "Content 2", "Content 3", "Content 4", "Content 5" },
                { "Content 1", "Content 2", "Content 3", "Content 4", "Content 5" } };

        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

        gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.RELATIVE;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;

        gbc.weightx = 1;
        gbc.weighty = 1;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;

        JTable table = new JTable(contents, columns);
        add(new JScrollPane(table), gbc);       
        
        gbc.weightx = 1;
        gbc.weighty = 1;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        
        JButton button = new JButton("Button");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(button);
        add(panel, gbc);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        GridBagPanel gbp = new GridBagPanel();
        frame.add(gbp);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        
    }
}
```

The result is the following:

[image: Result]

Is there a way to fix the height of the scroll pane's viewport to the height of its parent container so that the entire `JFrame` is being filled by its components?
The alignment of the button should stick to the border of the scroll pane, not like shown in the screenshot.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

Thanks to Hovercraft Full Of Eels I've come up with the following fix:

```java
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;

public class LayoutTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        String[] columns = { "Column 1", "Column 2", "Column 3", "Column 4" };
        String[][] contents = { { "Content 1", "Content 2", "Content 3", "Content 4", "Content 5" },
                { "Content 1", "Content 2", "Content 3", "Content 4", "Content 5" },
                { "Content 1", "Content 2", "Content 3", "Content 4", "Content 5" },
                { "Content 1", "Content 2", "Content 3", "Content 4", "Content 5" } };
        
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel wrapper = new JPanel();
        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();      
        JButton button = new JButton("Button");
        JTable table = new JTable(contents, columns);
        JScrollPane scrollpane = new JScrollPane(table);
        wrapper.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        
        buttonPanel.add(button);
        
        wrapper.add(scrollpane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        wrapper.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        
        frame.add(wrapper);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: An obvious suggestion is to set the grid bag constraints weighty property to 1.0 or some other non-zero number, e.g., `gbc.weighty = 1;`, but I assume that you've tried this already.

Comment: It works fine if I set weightx and weighty to 1, but if I have another `JButton` underneath in the `GridBagLayout`, then it sticks to the actual lower border of the scrollpane when resizing, which doesn`t really exist anymore.

Comment: Where is this information in your question? Put the JButton in its own JPanel, add that JPanel to the same container using appropriate grid bag constraints.

Comment: I didn't initially think this would change anything about the solution, but I'm happy to include it in my post now.

Comment: You probably don't need to update the question at this time but rather just add the JButton and its container using a gbc.gridy = 1

Comment: That is still not really working. You can see in the edited post.

Comment: OK, nest JPanels. Outer panel should use BorderLayout. Place the gridbaglayout using JPanel into its BorderLayout.CENTER position (or skip the GBL and just add the JScrollPane there). Add the JButton-containing JPanel to the BorderLayout-using outer JPanel to the `BorderLayout.PAGE_END` position. The key is to continually experiment to find the best solution.

Comment: Or use different weighty values for the upper and lower component to allow for different amounts of stretching of the components. Shoot, make the lower JPanel's weighty = 0.0 and it won't expand vertically.

Comment: Thank you a lot! I added the fix to the post.